# django form not saving to database(no error message)

Tags: python, django

First of all, I apologize for using a translator because I am not familiar with English.

My Views.py

```
def my_create_view(request):
    if "reg" in request.method == 'POST':
        first_form = FirstRegForm(request.POST, prefix='firstform')
        second_form = SecondRegForm(request.POST, prefix='secondform')
        if all([first_form.is_valid(), second_form.is_valid()]):
            form = first_form.save(commit=False)
            form.created_name = request.user.user_name
            form.save()
            formm = second_form.save(commit=False)
            formm.shop_seq = form
            formm.save()
            return redirect('someview')
    else:
        first_form = FirstRegForm(prefix='store')
        second_form = SecondRegForm(prefix='input')
    return render(request, 'app/template.html', {'first_form': first_form, 'second_form': second_form})
```

My Models.py

```
from django.db.models import Max

class My_user(AbstractBaseUser):
  shop_seq = models.ForeignKey('My_shop', null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, db_column="shop_seq")
  user_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)

class My_shop(models.Model):
  shop_seq = models.CharField(primary_key=True, editable=False, max_length=5)
  shop_name = models.CharField(max_length=20, null=True)
  shop_code = models.CharField(max_length=15, null=True, unique=True)
  shop_address = models.CharField(max_length=40, null=True)
  shop_tel = models.CharField(max_length=20, null=True)
  created_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True)

  def save(self, **kwargs):
    if not self.shop_seq:
      max = Rate.objects.aggregate(shop_seq_max=Max('shop_seq'))['shop_seq_max'] + 1
      self.shop_seq = "{:05d}".format(max if max is not None else 1)
    super().save(*kwargs)

class My_model(models.Model):
  model_id = models.BigAutoField(primary_key=True)
  my_field = models.CharField(max_length=20, null=True)
  some_field = models.CharField(max_length=20, null=True)
  shop_seq = models.ForeignKey('My_shop', on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, db_column="shop_seq", related_name="shop_model")
```

My Forms.py

```
class FirstRegForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = My_shop
        fields = ('shop_name', 'shop_code', 'shop_address', 'shop_tel',)

class SecondRegForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = My_model
        fields = ('my_field', 'some_field',)
```

My Template.py

```
<form method="post">{% csrf_token %}
  {{ first_form.shop_name }}
  {{ first_form.shop_code }}
  {{ first_form.shop_address }}
  {{ first_form.shop_tel }}
  {{ second_form.my_field }}
  {{ second_form.some_field }}
  <input class="btn btn-dark" name="reg" type="submit" value="reg">
</form>
```

If you submit it in this state, it will not be saved in the db.(no error message)

What's wrong with my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line will always be evaluated to false:

```
if "reg" in request.method == 'POST'
```

You should change it to:

```
if request.method == 'POST':
```

Comment: Thank you! It worked.
However, in my template, there is a button that opens the modal window when you press it, and the this command(if request.method == 'POST') works when you press it. What should I do?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't understand your question, you mean it's not working with modal windows?

Comment: My template has two buttons. <input name="reg" type="submit" value="reg"> and <button data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#CancelModal">Cancel</button>
and modal <div class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" id="CancelModal">

Comment: However, the Cancel button does not run modals and functions the same as the Registration button.

Comment: Ok, the problem is in the "cancel" button, it is routing to the same view as "Register" button, so you need to create another view which will handle "cancel" requests, and add `formaction` attribute in your "cancel" button, i.e. `<button formaction="your_url">Cancel</button>`